# Replace values in Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

I want to replace values in columns using if loop:

If value in column [D] is not same as any values in [A,B,C] then replace column with first NaN with D, and if there is no NaN in a row, create a new column [E] and add value from column [D] in column [E].

```
ID    A    B    C    D 

0    22   32   NaN   22
1    25   13   NaN   15
2    27   NaN  NaN   20
3    29   10   16    29
4    12   92   33    55
```

I want output to be:

```
ID    A     B    C     D    E

 0    22   32   NaN   22
 1    25   13   15    15
 2    27   20   NaN   20
 3    29   10   16    29
 4    12   92   33    55   55
```

Comment: Please consider providing the solution you have tried so far, otherwise it will make you look like you are asking someone to write some code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List = [[22  , 32 ,  None ,  22],
        [25  , 13 ,  None ,  15],
        [27  , None ,  None ,  20],
        [29  , 10 ,  16 ,  29],
        [12  , 92 ,  33 ,  55]]

for Row in List:
    Target_C = Row[3]
    if Row.count(Target_C) < 2:                      # If there is no similar condetion pass 
        None_Found = False                           # Small bool to check later if there is no None !
        for enumerate_Column in enumerate(Row):      # get index for each list
            if(None in enumerate_Column):            # if  there is None gin the row
                Row[enumerate_Column[0]] = Target_C  # replace None with column D
                None_Found = True                    # Change None_Found to True
            if(None_Found):                          # Break the loop if found None
                break                                
        if(None_Found == False):                     # if you dont found None add new clulmn
            Row.append(Target_C)
```

[My Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amw12.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
a = df.isnull()  
b = (a[a.any(axis=1)].idxmax(axis=1)) 
nanindex = b.index

check = (df.A!=df.D) & (df.B!=df.D) & (df.C!=df.D)
commonind = check[~check].index

replace_ind_list = list(nanindex.difference(commonind))
new_col_list = df.index.difference(list(set(commonind.tolist()+nanindex.tolist()))).tolist()

df['E']=''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for val in new_col_list:
        if index == val:
            df.at[index,'E'] = df['D'][index]
    for val in replace_ind_list:
        if index == val:
            df.at[index,b[val]] = df['D'][index]
df
```

**Output**

```
    ID  A   B        C       D  E
0   0   22  32.0    NaN     22  
1   1   25  13.0    15.0    15  
2   2   27  20.0    NaN     20  
3   3   29  10.0    16.0    29  
4   4   12  92.0    33.0    55  55
```